# byte compiler warning: called with 2 arguments, but accepts only 1

Tags: byte-compilation

When I byte compile an elisp file via `emacs -batch -f batch-byte-compile` I get **Warning: load-theme called with 2 arguments, but accepts only 1**. The code in question:

`(load-theme 'solarized-light t)`

The source in Emacs 25.1's custom.el: `(defun load-theme (theme &optional no-confirm no-enable)` ...

Similarly I get **set-frame-font called with 3 arguments, but accepts
    only 1-2** when set-frame-font's help says: `(set-frame-font FONT &optional KEEP-SIZE FRAMES)`

Which is confused, the byte compiler or I; and why?

Comment: I created a one line file with your first example in it. It compiled without a hiccup. There must be something more going on here. I don't think anyone can help without a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

A guess would be that you are byte-compiling in an older Emacs version, which does not support the additional arguments.

For example, if you byte-compile with Emacs 23 then you will get such warnings, because those args are not supported.

Comment: Nope; this is in Emacs 25.1.  This was happening in Emacs 24 too and I just ignored it then. But as long as I upgraded / was pruning my emacs initialization I thought I'd ask. Given @harald's comment I guess I am going to have to dig deeper.

Comment: Do you see the bad behavior when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file? If so, consider reporting a bug, providing a step-by-step recipe: `M-x report-emacs -bug`. If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the part that causes the problem. You can use command `comment-region` to comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8,... of the file. Use `C-u` with the command to uncomment the region.

Comment: Well, this was happening in my init file, which through decades of habit I byte compile.

Comment: Actually in what my init file would normally contain, which through decades of habit I byte compile and keep in a separate file while my actual init file just loads that file.)  I 'fixed' the issue by simply removing the problematic lines that were related to old, pre-custom cruft anyway.) If I discover the actual cause I'll post that here.

Comment: Bingo...........